# OAuth Authorization Code Flow with PKCE on stateless backend

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, pkce

I'm currently working on a solution where I need to authorize with a OAuth provider that is using Authorization Code with PKCE. I am trying to authorize from my stateless API backend (PHP Laravel shouldn't be relevant though).

The issue I am facing is PCKE sends a code challenge created from a unique hashed code verifier. This works fine until the callback url is hit and I attempt to get the token from the OAuth provider.

When I make a request to get the token I need to send the previous code verifier in order to validate the request and receive the access token.

This lead onto my issue, due to my api backend being stateless I have no way of storing the initial code verifier in session so I can't send it when making a request to the token URL. I have got it working by just hardcoding the code verifier to a known value but this defeats the point.

My question is, is there anyway to use the OAuth Authorization Code Flow with PKCE on a stateless backend?

Comment: If my api backend is confidential is it already to hardcode the code verifier in my env file? i'm just thinking this will basically act as a secret so wouldn't it be fine?

Comment: PKCE is primarily meant for untrusted clients, like SPA's. So you could just *not* use PKCE if the server made it optional, as long as your server does the heavy lifting. I can't help but wondering how hard can it be to spin up a Redis or a database though in like any environment.

Comment: @LukeRayner What do you need the token for at your server? Does it have a role of an OAuth2 client? What is your frontend? Is it stateless as well?

Comment: @Evert thank you for explaining this. We do have a MySQL database but if multiple users are signing in at once I’m not sure how I’d fetch the correct token since I don’t have any reference to the users session to collect the right key. Im happy to use the code verifier as a secret if it’s not a security risk.

Comment: @JánHalaša we have a frontend (vuejs) and a backend (PHP) which currently have its own authentication method. I now need to allow the user to sign in via a custom made OAuth provider which uses PKCE. The user would login via the custom OAuth provider but I’d then need to issue a separate token for our backend system allowing the frontend and backend to communicate. Due to having to issue a backend token still I want to handle the OAuth authentication on the backend and then if it passes store the OAuth token and issue our own token to the frontend.

Comment: @LukeRayner the OAuth2 token for your backend, does it have to be authorized by your user or you need just a token to get to a service that requires it (having the resource server role)?

Comment: @JánHalaša it has to be authorised by the user, the access token the backend provided allows the user to access all their own details I.e account details, clients, contacts etc… that’s why I’d like to manage authorising to the other OAuth provider via the backend since the frontend doesn’t really care about the details that provides

Comment: @LukeRayner you can generate a unique temporary id in your database and place it in the `state` parameter in the oauth2 flow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the described configuration - your PHP backend is an OAuth2 client, I would use the `state` auth request parameter ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)) as a key for saving the `code_verifier`. The `state` parameter will be returned to you with an auth code.

So you generate random (different) values for `state` and `code_verifier` and save them as a key-value pair in a database (or somewhere else). When a response from the OAuth2 server comes, try to find the `code_verifier` by the `state` value received from the OAuth2 server.

You can also use your Vue.js frontend as an OAuth2 client, which is stateful, and send an access token to your backend whenever necessary.

Access tokens use to be short lived, so if you need to make more than one request, you will need to take care of generating new ones using a refresh token. Consider that when deciding where to keep the OAuth2 tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using the state parameter. I didn't even think of using that for this scenario, my only question is would this be vulnerable? If someone intercepted the request back to my server during authorization and steals the authorization code they also now have the state value which would get them the code verifier from my database making it kind of useless. If instead I hardcoded the code verifier for all requests and treated it as a "secret" the attacker would have no way of obtaining the code verifier value. I'm just trying to make sure I use a secure approach

Comment: The state and the code_verifier values should be different - the code_verifier should stay safe in your database and the state value will be the key for finding the right code_verifier when you receive a response from the OAuth2 server. This way, you will also verify that the state value is correct - the one you originally sent. Delete it from DB after using it.

Comment: Sorry I was concerned that if they hijacked the request containing the auth_code and state they'd be able to use the state to then get the code_verifier. Even if they were different, the state would be the key to get the correct code_verifier from my database. Couldn't they just call my callback URL themselves pass in the values they stole and they'd then get access to the code_verifier? Whereas if the state wasn't used to get the code_verifier and instead it acted as a "secret" even if the request got hijacked and they stole the auth_code they wouldn't be able to obtain the code_verifier.

Comment: Thanks for helping me so far. I'm just speaking my mind and appreciate anymore help you can provide.

Comment: I didn't realise I can use a "client secret" and the code_verifier at the same time which is why I have been confused. Due to my backend being the OAuth client shall I send the "client secret" and code_verifier to get the access token? The dev who setup the OAuth provider never provided me with a "client secret" which is why I presumed I can't use one but I guess he thought I'd be authenticating via a public OAuth client.

Comment: PKCE is usually used for public clients that cannot hold a client secret (like browser or mobile apps). It can be used along with a secret, but if you didn't get a secret, then you probably don't need it. 
Concerning the man-in-the-middle attacks, if an attacker can intercept and read all your encrypted network communication (HTTPS), then yes, your system is seriously compromised. But it's at the level that OAuth2 cannot cover. And if an attacker sends a "OAauth2 server response"-like request, he doesn't get your token-endpoint-request containing the code verifier - it's a different request.